# Undefined property: WP_Query::$post

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, warnings

I am working on some rather elaborate comparisons between metadata and having a bit of trouble correctly referring to results from my query. The first query to establish `$team_is_home` works fine but as soon as I try to capture the ID of the posts where the `$team_is_home`it goes a bit haywire and I get warnings saying: "Undefined property: WP_Query::$post "

```
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'match_report',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
                 'key' => 'report_home-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '=',
           ),
       )                                  
     );

    $hometeams = new WP_Query($args);       
    $team_is_home =  $hometeams->found_posts;
    $scorehome = get_post_meta($hometeams->post->ID, 'report_homescore');
```

How should I be reffering to `$hometeams->post->ID` to avoid getting this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `post` field of WP_Query is current post ID and not post object. But I don't think you should use it before calling `the_post()` method.

Normally you should do it in this way:

```
$args = ...
$hometeams = new WP_Query( $args );
$teamishome = $hometeams->have_posts();
while ( $hometeams->have_posts() ) {
  $hometeams->the_post();
  $scorehome = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'report_homescore', true); // you want only one meta, not all array I guess.
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. I hadn't thought about it not being in its own loop (its already in another one.) Methinks this code is going to be very loopy.

Comment: It seems I have another problem now. Because I changed `$hometeams->the_post();`my first loop is no longer valid. I may have to ask another question. Arhg!

Comment: Add wp_reset_postdata after enwhile of your $hometeams loop.

Comment: I did but it only resets that weren't affected by $hometeams. The others are reset to the ID of the page I am on.

Comment: I was thinking I had to reset the original query http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103508/cloning-a-wp-query

Comment: Resetting postdata should be enough. You can also use wp_reset_query - it will recompute global wp_query variable.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working as it resets hometeams to the global variable and not to my original teams query.

Answer (score 2):

If you `var_dump($hometeams);` you will see that `$hometeams->post` is set to the first post in the query results even before `$hometeams->the_post` runs. `WP_Query` initializes it automatically *if you have posts in the result set*.

The "Undefined Property" warning occurs when your result set is empty, and thus `$hometeams->post` can't be set/initialized.

You need to check that you have a populated `$hometeams->post` before trying to use it. If you use `while ( $hometeams->have_posts() ) {` as suggested in one answer or `foreach($hometeams->posts as $key => $post){` as in another you are looping over `$hometeams->posts` and so are avoiding the issue with `$hometeams->post` completely.

Another option would be...

```
if (!empty($hometeams->post)) {
  $scorehome = get_post_meta($hometeams->post->ID, 'report_homescore'); 
}
```

... however, since your query does not contain `'posts_per_page' => 1` you need to be using a loop or you will only get one of the potentially large number of posts in the result set.

Be sure to run [`reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after your secondary Loop to reset `$post`, or [`wp_reset_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) if necessary.

Comment: I went with the loop option as it made the most sense and as I wanted to include an else statement in the event there were no posts (matches) which will be how the season will start. I'm having a hard time resetting the post query as when I use `wp_reset_postdata()` it resets the loop to the page I am on. I am now trying to clone the query I was thinking I had to reset the original query http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103508/cloning-a-wp-query

Comment: Yes, it probably does make the most sense to use the Loop from the accepted answer, but that answer didn't explain _why_ exactly you were having the problem, so I did.

Comment: You're right, and thank you. I am having a difficult time getting my head around WP_Query. I'll certainly take any help I can get!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `foreach` also

```
$args = ...
$hometeams = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach($hometeams->posts as $key => $post){
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'report_homescore', true);
}
```