# cloning a WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm working with several nested loops in order to create a statistics table for teams in a league and I'm having trouble getting my original query back. I've read that I should clone the original query but can't find an explanation of how to do it or where to put it. Here's what I've come up with (definitely not working):

```
$team = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'team_page') ); 
$i=0;

if ( $team->have_posts() ) {
while ( $team->have_posts() ) { 
    $team->the_post();

$team_id = $team->posts[$i]->ID;        
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'match_report',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                 'key' => 'report_home-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '=',
              ),
              array(
                 'key' => 'report_away-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '='
              )
       ),
        array(
            'key' => 'report_type',
            'value' => 'cup',
            'compare' => '='                  ),                                  
     );

    $reports_played = new WP_Query($args); 
    $played = $reports_played->found_posts;
    $i++;   


$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'match_report',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
                 'key' => 'report_home-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '=',
           ),
       )                                  
     );

    $hometeams = new WP_Query($args);
    $team_is_home =  $hometeams->found_posts;   

$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'match_report',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
                 'key' => 'report_away-select',
                 'value' => $team_id,
                 'compare' => '=',
           ),
       )                                  
     );

    $awayteams = new WP_Query($args);       
    $team_is_away =  $awayteams->found_posts;

$temp_query = clone $wp_query;

if ( $hometeams->have_posts() ) {
while ( $hometeams->have_posts() ) {
$hometeams->the_post();
$scorehome = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'report_homescore', true);
}
} else {
$scorehome = 0;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
$wp_query = clone $temp_query; ?>           

                    <tr>

                        <td class="teamname"><?php the_title(); ?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $played;?></td>                  

                        <td>9</td><!-- won -->

                        <td>0</td><!-- draw -->

                        <td>2</td><!-- lost -->

                        <td class="goalinfo"></td><!-- goals for -->

                        <td class="goalinfo">10</td><!-- goals against -->

                        <td class="goalinfo">33</td><!-- goal difference -->

                        <td class="total">27</td><!-- goal total -->
                    </tr>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to "get your query back". Your queries are all stored in different objects-- `$team`, `$reports_played`, the original `$wp_query`, etc. Just access the particular object that you need to use.

This is untested but to get functions like `the_title` working, run `$query_object_name->the_post()` at the top of each Loop iteration and `$post = $parent_object_name->post` after each sub-Loop and before returning to the parent Loop to put the `global` post object back to the parent object's `$post`. I *think* that will work. `wp_reset_postdata` will reset to the *main* query so I doubt it will work for deeply nested queries.

Comment: I see. I realise now that I was using `the_title();` where I should have been using `$team->posts[$i]->post_title;` Thanks once again for your help. So just out of curiosity when would I need to clone a query? I read about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops).

Comment: You only (well, mostly only) need the clone the query when you need to overwrite `$wp_query`, which should be very rarely-- most likely to get pagination working with a secondary query but even in that circumstance there is probably another way to proceed.

Comment: So if I _really_ wanted to use `the_title();` that would be the way to do it?

Comment: I tried testing it (just for fun) and got a fatal error. Actually, I was just curious and thought it might help with testing. Thank you for your suggestions. I'm sure I will be back for more in the course of all this.

Comment: @mantis If you got a fatal error, why is it marked as solution then?

Comment: It was marked as a solution and then edited. It did solve my problem but you are right in that it didn't exactly solve the original question.

Comment: Incidently, the fatal error was my mistake. It sort of works in that it lists the title of the `$teams` query but the queried object is still the original query.